# Como saber si se hizo un insert en base de datos Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, webservice

Necesito crear un webservice en el cual pueda verificar en una base de datos Mysql si se agrego un nuevo registro en una tabla. Esto con el fin de llamar el webservice en un thread como un servicio de android para que cuando se agregue un nuevo registro enviar una notificacion.

lo que pasa es que yo no voy a ser el que haga el insert, va ser un script el cual alimentara una base de datos de otra. lo que se me ocurre es contar las filas de la tabla y almacenarlas en android studio puede ser en las preferencias o una variable y cuando sea mayor el nuevo numero de filas mande notificacion
no se que tan viable sea esto?

y como podria hacer para traer el numero de filas en PDO?

Comment: Amigo lograste resolver el inconveniente ando buscando algo similar a lo que tú planteas. Si es así me podrías comentar que usaste ?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer un `row count` posteriormente a la inserción, o si quieres algo más avanzado, ligado con si el `statement` se ha ejecutado con éxito, puedes utilizar esto en PDO:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users ... ? ? ? ");
$statement->execute($data);

if( $statement ) return "Su registro ha sido insertado con éxito";
```

Porque si se ejecuta correctamente el `$stmt`, devuelve `true`.

Comment: hola. gracias por responder mira lo que pasa es que yo no voy a ser el q haga el insert, va ser un script el cual alimentara de una base de datos a otra. lo que se me ocurre es contar las filas de la tabla y almacenarlas en android studio puede ser en las preferencias o una variable y cuando sea mayor el nuevo numero de filas mande notificacion

Comment: Alex, por favor agrega toda esa informacion y todo lo que sepas sobre tu problema a la pregunta. Porque si no recibes buenas respuestas, pero parciales porque no se conoce tu problematica entera. @ALEXMAURICIOCADAVIDQUICENO